# Action Item goes to overflow but there's enough room

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am just getting started with ActionBarSherlock and just wondering if there's enough room to display an Action Item Icon why does it go to overflow?

My App is intended to work on both phones and tablets.  Functionality is perfect on tablet but having difficulty displaying the action item icon on the phone, it always goes to overflow even though there is plenty of room in portrait mode.  BTW, work fine in landscape mode.

I have a SherlockFragmentActivity that has 1 action item in the options Menu.  It displays as intended in Landscape but goes to overflow when in portrait.  I have tried using the "showAsAction=always" but that didn't work either.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I am testing on a DroidX Android Version 2.2.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/ic_tv"
    android:icon="@drawable/image_tv"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned I just started implementing ActionBar into my application.  So after much frustration I did manage to find a solution.  I added the following into my AndroidManifest.

```
android:uiOptions="none"
```

This is the default value.  For my purpose this works just fine since the app will only have 1 action item for now. I hope this helps anyone that has encountered the same scenario.